# Confusion about the compouding sentences with 'not to say'

Tags: compound-sentences

If a sentence is formed like this,

> There is a deep ambivalence, not to say hypocrisy, when we notice that ..

I am confused what exactly the author emphasizing. Is he saying, the hypocrisy is obvious but I am highlighting the ambivalence; or is he drawing readers attention to 'ambivalence' and asking them not to confuse it with 'hypocrisy'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[not to say](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/say?q=not%20to%20say#say__29):

> used to introduce a stronger alternative or addition to something already said:
>
> *it is easy to become sensitive, **not to say** paranoid*

[not to say](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/not_to_say):

> Even; perhaps; almost.
>
> At first Marc was somewhat shocked, then he burst out laughing and finally came to the conclusion that actually it was all rather sad, **not to say** stupid.

Depending on the context, you could mean that the alternative is definite or simply a good possibility. In the OP's example, the writer is leaning towards the definite.

Answer (score 5):

In OP's context, [not to say](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/not-to-say) means *and possibly even* or *if not* (i.e. - not definitely, but maybe).

In effect, whilst the writer is definitely prepared to say there is *deep ambivalence* (felt by observers), he's diffident about going so far as to say there's *hypocrisy* (being observed).

One could say this is a mild form of [paralipsis](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/paralipsis), typified by ["not to mention *xxxx*"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2293/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-not-to-mention). In that more overt form, the speaker claims he won't mention *xxxx* in the very act of so doing (but he definitely and explicitly means *"xxxx **really does apply** here"*). In OP's case, the writer shies away from explicit accusations of hypocrisy, he simply raises the possibility in the reader's mind.

I'd also say that to me the sentence is poor English. The *"ambivalence"* is an attribute *experienced internally* by the writer and/or other observers, but the *hypocrisy* (if indeed there is any) would be an *externally assigned* attribute of whatever/whoever is under consideration. I think it's bad style, **if not** downright unsettling, to conjoin attributes with totally different referents in this way.

Comment: **at bad style** or **a bad style**?

Comment: I like the experienced-assigned distinction that you make, but surely we can associate with every externally-observed behavior a corresponding internally-observed experience? It seems reasonable to assume that being a hypocrite feels a certain way and that we can observe a person's ambivalence to some degree. I'm not interested in the accuracy with which we can do this in any situation. I just wanted to note that I think we can and do make connections between these distinct spheres and so can perhaps bridge the conceptual gap that you point out, maybe with too much difficulty for your taste.

Comment: @Rachel: But my very point is that the writer isn't talking about what *"being a hypocrite feels [like]"*. He "extrapolates" from *an internal feeling of ambivalence* to *an external instance of possible hypocrisy* (not internal *what it's like to detect hypocrisy in others*). It doesn't work for me when the writer tries to map these totally different concepts onto one possible "scale" against which to measure whatever he's talking about (when we notice that ..).

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice on the first read that the author was the one feeling ambivalence.

Comment: You believe there is a difference of substance between "not to *say*" and "not to *mention*"? Why? How are *say* and *mention* different here?

Comment: @ΜετάEd: Certainly there's a difference, as indicated by my first link to the Cambridge Dictionaries definition *not to say=and possibly even*. Their definition for *not to mention* is *used when you want to **emphasize** something that you **are** adding to a list*. They're both **idiomatic** usages - you can't claim they're equivalent just because in other contexts *say* and *mention* can mean exactly the same thing.